# New-AzureReservedIP: What´s the difference between ReservedIPName and Label?

Tags: powershell, azure, configuration, ip-address, static-ip-address

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23643883/1051244) and [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/) one can create reserved IP adresses in Microsoft Azure.

Used Powershell command: New-AzureReservedIP.

What are the powershell parameters -ReservedIPName and -Label used for? What´s the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with pretty much all of the Azure service management APIs, the Name is a unique identifier that you use when calling other APIs (ie. passing the name into the New-AzureVM command).  The label is just a descriptive label that you can use for your own purposes (ie. "Static IP for Billing system").

Comment: Thanks kwill, as you said the Name is a unique identifier. For example it is used to delete the reserved IP with Remove-AzureReservedIP.